# Getting the previous line in Jython

Tags: python

I want to print the line immediately before the searched string. How can I do that?

Lets say my two lines are

```
AADRG
SDFJGKDFSDF
```

and I am searching for `SDF`. I have found `SDFJGKDFSDF`, but how can I obtain the previous line `AADRG`? Does  `file.readline()-1` work?

Comment: what happen to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504899/string-search-and-write-into-file-in-jython

Answer (score 4):

```
lastLine = ""
for line in lines:
   if line.find("SDF"):
      print lastLine

   lastLine = line
```

or

```
lines = open("file").readlines()
for line in lines:
   if "SDF" in line:
      # test for not being the first line of course.
      print lines[lines.index(line) - 1]
```

Comment: You can use `"SDF" in line` instead of `string.find()`

Comment: Or at least use 'abc'.find('b') instead of the string module.